# Fundamental theorem on homomorphisms for structures with only identity element

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

Is there a version of the fundamental theorem on homomorphisms for binary structures that only have a unique identity element? I'm guessing that there isn't because without the cancelation laws I can't find a way to show that a homomorphism preserves the identity, so there is no sence in defining the kernel. If that's correct, is there a version of the theorem for structures with an identity and with the cancelation laws? In general, what is the most general structure for which the theorem holds? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is not. Groups are the most general structure on which they hold, at least as far as I know. You need inversion in order to have a well behaved kernel.

Comment: The notion of [congruence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_relation) is the generalisation of the idea of a kernel of a group homomorphism that is most widely studied. In some cases congruences correspond precisely to certain kinds of substructure, e.g., normal subgroups in group theory. Ideals or filters serve this purpose in [boolean algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(structure)) which (*pace* @DonThousand) don't have an inverse operation in general. I don't know of any general results of the sort you are asking for.